# Ошибка запуска selenium на сервере linux (python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

[image: Ошибка в терминале]

Установил chromedriver нужной версии, в итоге вот такая ошибка, гуглил ее, но ответы не помогали, пожалуйста помогите мне решить данную проблему!

Comment: На linux server не рекомендую пользоваться chromedriver. Пользуйтесь нативным для этой ос firefox и geckodriver. Гимора будет в разы меньше